# Get a frame from video URI on android (java)

Tags: java, android, video

I'm trying to get a frame or thumbnail from a video picked from gallery, I cut the video and I need to get a frame from that result. I try with this but in some cases (video is 3 seconds) it returns null:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever mMMR = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
mMMR.setDataSource(this, selectedVideoFinal);          
Bitmap thumbnail = mMMR.getFrameAtTime(1000000, MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: how do you cut the video?

Comment: I use a library for that https://github.com/titansgroup/k4l-video-trimmer

Comment: there is a concept called "Sync or Key" frames in video production, so maybe the key-frame interval configuration that used in the provided library is too much, and because of that your output video after trimming does not contain any "keyframe" which is required for MediaMetadataReriever to get a frame

Comment: That's the reason why I use "MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST" and not "MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST"_SYNC